# How to play sound on boot via cron

Tags: linux, boot, cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

In `/etc/crontab`, I have this line:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/nvlc -L /home/pi/Music/loop.flac
```

It does not play that file on boot. It does nothing. No sound comes out from the speakers.

If I type `/usr/bin/nvlc -L /home/pi/Music/loop.flac` on the command line and press Enter, it enters some sort of CLI VLC and starts playing the file. Sound comes out from the speakers. Clearly, the command is working, but it ignores the fact that it's supposed to run it at boot.

Why? What can possibly be wrong? I even used the full path to "nvlc" to avoid any issues with "different PATHs" or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You better try other command line players like mpg123, mpg321 or mplayer, and make sure the audio service has already started by giving it a delayed run, e.g.

```
@reboot sleep 15;/usr/bin/mplayer whatever.flac
```

Comment: Well, the sleep thing makes sense, but it's unfortunate since I want it to start playing the sample as soon as possible, and it already takes "forever" to boot it up, but I will give that a try for sure. Not sure why you want me to use something other than VLC, though? Also, that mplayer command won't loop it, will it?